# Control strip stop works after about 24h of working + sleep, required SMC reset

Tags: keyboard, catalina, sleep-wake, power-management

Control strip stop works after about 24h of working + sleep, required SMC reset

Problem appears then i dropped about 0.06 L Coca Cola on Upper-Left side of my MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019). First 2-3 days TouchBar constantly stop works and dissapears from USB devices (Touch Bar Backlight). But after 2-3 days it just freeze with no light disappearance.

One of my USB-C from left side now constantly lose power adapter ware. And TouchBar(control strip) stop works after a ~24h of working + macbook sleep. Required SMC reset.

OS: 10.15.7 (19H1824)

Could you please help me to localize my problem? Should i call ioreg with specific args to highlight this problem?

Comment: Liquid damage.  Coke is acidic.  Take it to Apple before it gets worse.

Comment: Now in 6/7 cases enought to reboot macbook to fix unresponsible control strip. Workaround with reboot works when possible to use CS by frequently clicking. 
In case if it is unresponsible at all - SMC restoring required - it appears about a 1 time per week.
100% problem appears after notebook close-open (hibernation/sleep problem?)
But not 100% notebook close-open leads to the problem, about a 50-60% it is wake-up/resume without any problems.
Relaunch software control strip or touch bar via 'kill' doesn't helps at all.
Probably the line with touch screen is overheating during the sleep?